# D15 to d16 swap/possible problem

Tags: honda, manual-transmission, wiring, swap

I've got a 95 del sol with d15b7 and looking at a d16y4. I'm wondering about trans mount up and wiring being that I have obd1 with obd2 port, and the motor is 96-97 jdm. I've heard something about crank sensor wiring while some said you need to wire it to get it to crank. I've also seen people say bolt right up and go.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'm not sure whether your D15b7 is fuel injected or not. If not, you'd have to do a complete EFI conversion to run the D16y4 in there. It appears the bellhousing bolt pattern for both are the same, but I'm seeing mixed reviews on whether the flywheel/clutch/starter will work between the two. Have you considered looking for a JDM replacement for your Del Sol? JDM engines can usually be found fairly cheap (like in the $500 arena where I live).